# How to make game functions available based on in-game clock?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a game with an in game clock (Think Stardew Valley.) in Visual Studio.  Time does not automatically advance though; doing things in game advances the clock.  I want some things to be available or unavailable depending on the time.

I currently have a bunch of localized if statements for checking the time before allowing another control to load.  It's spread out and messy.

```
if strDayOfWeek = FRIDAY then
   MessageBox.Show("The gate to Liz's farm is locked tight.  She's off today.")
else
   if (intHour > 7 and bolMorning = true) or ((intHour = 12 or intHour < 6) and bolMorning = false)
      'show Liz's farm control
   else
      MessageBox.Show("The gate to Liz's farm is locked tight.  It's not working hours.")
   end if
end if
```

That's more messy than I'd like.  And I have to do this for multiple things.
I would like to have something more like this:

```
if LizFarm.available = true then
   'show Liz's farm control
else
   if LizFarm.dayoff = true then
      MessageBox.Show("The gate to Liz's farm is locked tight.  She's off today.")
   else 
      MessageBox.Show("The gate to Liz's farm is locked tight.  It's not working hours.")
   end if 
end if
```

It looks cleaner, huh?

I'd also like to be able to set all the time constraints in one place.

Can anyone give me some ideas for cleaning this code up?  Thank you!

Comment: So, really you just want to set LizFarm.available? then enter your updated flow control?  Why not just LizFarm.available = (intHour > 7 and bolMorning = true) or ((intHour = 12 or intHour < 6) and bolMorning = false), then do your If LizFarm.avilable Then...

Comment: Sounds good, Hursey.  I'll give that a spin.

Comment: Did that answer your question? If so, please paste it into an answer do others can see the question has been answered.